# UICollectionViewController keeps rearranging itself from asynchronous image load

Tags: asynchronous, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my application. I get a bunch of image URLs on the main thread like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self populateCollection];
}

- (void)populateCollection
{
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[MTGJSONBridge JSONURLWithSetCode:@"LEA"]]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Json: %@", json);
    NSArray *cards = json[@"cards"];
    _URLs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:cards.count];
    for (NSDictionary *card in cards)
    {
        NSURL *imageURL = [MTGJSONBridge URLWithSetCode:@"LEA" cardName:card[@"imageName"]];
        if (imageURL)
            [_URLs addObject:imageURL];
    }
}
```

This gets me about 300 URLs in 0.2 seconds. Then I try to load the images from each URL asynchronously like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"reuseIdentifier";
    MTGCardCollectionCell *cell = (MTGCardCollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSURL *url = _URLs[indexPath.row];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // No explicit autorelease pool needed here.
        // The code runs in background, not strangling
        // the main run loop.
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // This will be called on the main thread, so that
            // you can update the UI, for example.
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

I also have this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _URLs.count;
}
```

The collection loads really quickly, and asynchronously too (I can scroll while things are loading, and I see new images pop up). The problem is that as I scroll up and down, even after all the images have loaded, the thing keeps rearranging itself in a random order: I'll be looking at one cell, and then it'll have its image switched with another for no apparent reason. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered a very easy solution:

```
if (cell.imageView.image == nil)
{
    NSURL *url = _URLs[indexPath.row];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // No explicit autorelease pool needed here.
        // The code runs in background, not strangling
        // the main run loop.
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // This will be called on the main thread, so that
            // you can update the UI, for example.
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Cell image isn't nil");
}
```

All I have to do is check if the cell isn't already loaded. Turns out the `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method is called whenever a cell comes into view. Even if it was just in the view.